# Moving an App from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: c#, windows, 32bit-64bit

We have a Windows Service app written in C# targeted for AnyCPU. It runs on a Win2003 (32bit) server. Recently it started to run out of memory.

What is involved in redeploying this service to a Win2003 (64bit) box. Do I need to recompile it and will the App get more memory if I do not recompile it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special if the exe is set for AnyCPU- the 64-bit CLR will load by default on a 64-bit machine. You just have to make sure you're REALLY AnyCPU ready (no unsafe OR safe 32-bit pointer math assumptions, etc). If you're running all managed code with no PInvokes, you should be in good shape.

Comment: The real question is: are you running out of memory because the app is flawed somehow, or just because you really NEED that much memory? If you're leaking, moving to 64bit just prolongs the inevitable.

Comment: This is a letter printing application. Every template is an XSL converting the data xml to a wordml file. The size is ~300k per template. Recently the number of templates almost doubled. We will get better about keeping them in memory but I need a sort term solution